# How to use Terraform to deploy AWS Sagemaker Notebook instance

Tags: jupyter-notebook, terraform, amazon-sagemaker

Good day

I have a local Jupyter notebook script that I would like to run from start to finish based on a Cloudwatch event.  The script it successfully started and stopped through two Lambdas (which works). However, I am now struggling deploying the Sagemaker instance with the local script I have as the "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" resource requires a "aws_sagemaker_code_repository".

Is it possible to provide the script by providing it as part of the terraform project like I do with a Lamdba?  I would very much like the project to be self contained and not have external dependencies (like code repos) just to deploy the instance. Would I have to create a temporary repo as part of the deploy to satisfy "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" requirements?

Thank you, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: Found an answer: https://github.com/noahweber1/medium_articles_code/blob/main/AWS_sagemaker_terraform/AWS_sagemaker_terraform/terraform/sagemaker.tf  In short: Use a standard image and just copy the script into the instance using the "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance_lifecycle_configuration" resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of pointers -

1. The notebook instance does not require a code repository, the default code repository is an optional resource (ref: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_notebook_instance). So, you should be able to create a notebook instance without adding a code repository.
2. What do you need the notebook instance for? If you're simply running a Python script, why not use training jobs that can be invoked using Lambda (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-training.html)? If you're running an `.ipynb` file, then you can run them as notebook jobs on a schedule (they don't support event-based scheduling though) - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/operationalize-your-amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebooks-as-scheduled-notebook-jobs/

Lifecycle scripts (LCC) are simply shell scripts that are executed on creating/starting a notebook. Jobs are better ways to run scripts/notebooks rather than starting and stopping an instance using Lambdas just to run a LCC script.